# I've got an image button and I want to be able to set the transparent parts to a color

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I've got an ImageButton:

[image]

and I want to make the transparent parts of the image into another color, while leaving the background white.  Is there a way to do that in xml (or code)?

I've tried:

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

and

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

but this changes the whole background to the different color and not the transparent part.  It leaves the transparent part white.

Comment: @pskink How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"`